# Python tKinter - When button is pressed in other view, title updates in main view (GUI)

Tags: python, user-interface, variables, tkinter, button

I was wondering if there was a way to update the title of a tKinter GUI window when a button in another window is pressed? Like shown in the picture bellow.

[Button pressed inserts * in title of main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV67K.png)

The secondary window is created by a secondary .py file that is imported into the main .py file because I have several "main.py" files that link in this secondary .py file.

Can **the button click**, or when **the variables updates** in the main file, be linked to the title function in the main file? :)

**Edit:**

Example code below, without the value of the variables that also needs to be imported from the secondary file to the main file.

Wishful try of code, but i get a circular error since both are importing each other.
(I can put the `from main_file import change_title` into `def title_update_main()` and get it to work sort of, with some errors, but that doesn't seem like the right way)

Example code from main_file.py:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from secondary_file import open_secondary_window

main_window = Tk()
main_window.geometry("300x300")
main_window.title("Main window")

open_secondary_window()

def change_title():
    main_window.title("Updated by button from secondary window")

main_window.mainloop()
```

Example code from secondary_file.py:

```
from tkinter import Toplevel, Button
from main_file import change_title

def open_secondary_window():
    secondary_window = Toplevel()
    secondary_window.geometry("270x350")
    secondary_window.title("Secondary window")

    def title_update_main():
        # This is the code that needs to be executed,
        # but that I haven't figured out how to connect to main file.
        change_title()
        print("Main window's title updated")

    title_update_button = Button(secondary_window, text="Update title main window", command=title_update_main)
    title_update_button.pack()
```

Comment: Any pointers on how that would look? With two different .py files 

Comment: I've made an example in the question, but with an error on circular import that needs to be fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating both windows in the same file, let's say `window1 = Tk()` and `window2 = TopLevel()` in `window2` you can simply add a button like this: `Button(window2, text='Click me', command=change_title).pack()` and make a function above like this: `def change_title():` and inside that function add this like of code: `window1.config(title='New title')`. If it doesn't work (it depends on your full code structure) you can try adding `global window1`.\

Comment: That works great if they’re in the same file. My problem is that they are in different files, since I have many other files that import this secondary .py file. And if a change is needed in this file, I dont’t want to change it in all the other files as well.

Comment: Okay, you can then make a function in `main.py` with `window1` and that function `change_title()` needs to contain this line of code: `window1.config(title='New title')`. And in `second.py` file you need to `from main import change_title` and use it in command part of a button that is created in `second.py` like this: `Button(window2, text='Click me', command=change_title).pack()`

Comment: That is something I've tried, but when I import both files into each other, i get a circular import error. Se my edit in the question with a minimum example :)

Comment: Put this line of code when importing in `main.py`: `if __name__ == '__main__': from secondary_file import open_secondary_window`. So now when you run second file it won't import its imports. It's because when you are importing, you also import imports, so if you are importing a file that imports you then it's a loop. So use a simple line of code that checks if the code is being executed because of its runned from exact script or from another file through imports, because when you import a file it auto executes it.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and that should work, but i get this error: "NameError: name 'open_secondary_window' is not defined"

Comment: Use a regular import like this: `import secondary_file as sf` and see if you can see it by auto completion with `sf.open_secondary_window()`

Comment: It finds it, but the same error appears. So i guess the __name__  == '__main__' isn't equal to True since it doesn't import the function from the secondary file.

Comment: Import it like this then: `from .secondary_file import open_secondary_window` add "." before file name

Comment: then this appears: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package". The files are in the same folder.

Comment: Okay, lets try to make your folder a python package by creating an empty file called like this: `__init__.py` in the same folder and then use relative import statement (the one with a dot "." before file name)

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything. Same error :p

Comment: If you made the __init__.py file then when importing use this: YOUR_FOLDER_NAME.second_file import *